# Navigate back to tab index with ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a tab layout with 5 tabs. When i navigate to the second tab and then to a subpage, navigating back with `ion-back-button` lands on the first tab. How can i go back to the last selected tab?

Any help much appreciated!

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
  { path: 'timetable', loadChildren: './timetable/timetable.module#TimetablePageModule' },
  { path: 'artistDetail/:id', loadChildren: './artist-detail/artist-detail.module#ArtistDetailPageModule' },
  { path: 'artist', loadChildren: './artist/artist.module#ArtistPageModule' },
];
```

Tab routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/(home:home)',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        outlet: 'home',
        component: HomePage
      },
      {
        path: 'timetable',
        outlet: 'timetable',
        component: TimetablePage
      },
      {
        path: 'artist',
        outlet: 'artist',
        component: ArtistPage
      }

    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/(home:home)',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

Tabs

```
  <ion-tab label="Dashboard" icon="home" href="/tabs/(home:home)">
    <ion-router-outlet name="home"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="Zeitplan" icon="time" href="/tabs/(timetable:timetable)">
    <ion-router-outlet name="timetable"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
[...]
```

Tab Page which navigates to subpage of tab with `routerLink`

```
  <div class="venue-box animated fadeIn fast delay-500ms" *ngFor="let artist of data" routerLink="/artistDetail/{{artist.id}}" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + artist?.imagePath + ')'}">
    <div class="box">
      <h1>{{artist?.name}}</h1>
      <p>{{artist?.subtitle}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Header on Subpage:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>{{artist}}</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 4):

In Ionic 4, ion-back-button with tab view contain bugs that needs to be fixed. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15216

Answer (score 3):

remove page routing from app-routing.module and then add the route of that page inside tabs.router.module
something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'tabs',
  component: TabsPage,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'home',
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          loadChildren: '../../pages/home/home.module#HomePageModule'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: 'jobsRequest',
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          loadChildren: '../../pages/Jobs/jobs-request/jobs-

request.module#JobsRequestPageModule'
            },
            {
              path: 'jobs-details',
              loadChildren: '../../pages/Jobs/jobs-details/jobs-details.module#JobsDetailsPageModule'
            }
          ]
        },
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: '/app/tabs/home',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
```

you can call jobs-details page like this :

```
this.router.navigate(['/app/tabs/jobsRequest/jobs-details', { IsFavorite: this.IsFavorite }]);
```

and from jobs-details page use:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>jobs details</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-back-button ></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: This must be the accepted answer ! I tried several solutions, this is the only working for me ! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I created an Ionic 4 [demo project](https://github.com/servrox/demo-ionic-tabs-back-button) with a tab based layout and workarounds for the `ion-back-button`.

The demo shows [two ways](https://github.com/servrox/demo-ionic-tabs-back-button#solutions-shown-in-demo) how to navigate from a *'tabbed page'* to a *'global page'* and back, **without losing tab-states**.

It's correct that the `ion-back-button` needs to be fixed, I think this is because the `ion-back-button` uses only the *main-IonRouterOutlet*, instead of also checking *tabs-IonRouterOutlet*.
Which means that the *StackController* inside the *main-IonRouterOutlet* only knows the route of the tabs module (e.g. 'tabs').

My custom [ion-back-button-tabs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ion-back-button-tabs) component accessing the problem explained above directly (also shown in [demo](https://github.com/servrox/demo-ionic-tabs-back-button#2-using-ion-back-button-tabs-component-s-global-page-two)). `ion-back-button-tabs` uses the `ion-back-button` internally, however, it's additionally checked whether to navigate to a *'tabbed page'* and if so, the last active tab route is determined.